# How to get the offset/position of each column generated with the canvasJs chart

Tags: jquery, html, canvasjs

I am using the Canvasjs charts for creating column chart.I want to get the location/position ,where the chart is getting drawn in the "chartContainer (Id of the div)".
Here is my code which I have created the sample.Here I want to get the location of each column chart either as offset value or position.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
      Reviewed = [{ x: 1, y: 10 },
    { x: 2, y: 15 },
    { x: 3, y: 25 },
    { x: 4, y: 30 },
    { x: 5, y: 28 },
    { x: 6, y: 10 },
    { x: 7, y: 15 },
    { x: 8, y: 25 },
    { x: 9, y: 30 },
    { x: 10, y: 28 },
    { x: 11, y: 10 },
    { x: 12, y: 15 },
    { x: 13, y: 25 },
    { x: 14, y: 30 },
    { x: 15, y: 28 },
    { x: 16, y: 10 },
    { x: 17, y: 15 },
    { x: 20, y: 25 },
    { x: 21, y: 30 },
    { x: 25, y: 28 },
    { x: 26, y: 10 },
    { x: 27, y: 15 },
    { x: 28, y: 25 },
    { x: 30, y: 30 },
    { x: 40, y: 28 }]


    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        zoomEnabled: true,
                width: 760,
                height: 50,
                theme: "theme4",
                toolTip: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                axisX: {
                    gridThickness: 0.0,
                    interval: 60,
                    labelFontSize: 0.1,
                    tickLength: 0.0,
                    lineThickness: 1
                },

                axisY: {
                    gridThickness: 0.0,
                    interval: 10,
                    labelFontSize: 0.1,
                    tickLength: 0.0,
                    lineColor: "white",
                    lineThickness: 0.1
                },
                dataPointWidth: 2,
                dataPointMaxWidth: 5,
      data: [
      {
         type: "column",
         cursor: "pointer",
         click: onClick,
         dataPoints: Reviewed
    });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Based on my reseach I could find the position of column in click event in onclick function of canvasJs chart like below.

```
 function onClick(e) {
                alert(e.dataPoint.x)//, userId, window.event);
                var a = parseInt(e.x) - 10;
                document.getElementById('indicator').style.width = a + 'px'
            }
```

It could give the location of column,but I want to get the position/offset value during the chart creation,Please help me to get the sloution.

any help will be very much helpful.Thanks

Comment: You can get the x and y from e.x and e.y and item value from e.dataPointIndex +1

Comment: e.x I can get with the click event, But I want the index/position value during chart render

Comment: e.dataPointIndex provides me the index, but I want the location/position where the column charts are getting rendex , say example like column1 rendered at position at 201px from left

Comment: You can get the mouse position using:
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    });

Comment: @mbadeveloper this is a mouse event which gives mouse movement positions. but actually I want the column chart render position

Comment: update the click event so you can get the mouse position

Answer (score 0):

```js
  window.onload = function () {
      Reviewed = [{ x: 1, y: 10 },
    { x: 2, y: 15 },
    { x: 3, y: 25 },
    { x: 4, y: 30 },
    { x: 5, y: 28 },
    { x: 6, y: 10 },
    { x: 7, y: 15 },
    { x: 8, y: 25 },
    { x: 9, y: 30 },
    { x: 10, y: 28 },
    { x: 11, y: 10 },
    { x: 12, y: 15 },
    { x: 13, y: 25 },
    { x: 14, y: 30 },
    { x: 15, y: 28 },
    { x: 16, y: 10 },
    { x: 17, y: 15 },
    { x: 20, y: 25 },
    { x: 21, y: 30 },
    { x: 25, y: 28 },
    { x: 26, y: 10 },
    { x: 27, y: 15 },
    { x: 28, y: 25 },
    { x: 30, y: 30 },
    { x: 40, y: 28 }]


    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        zoomEnabled: true,
                width: 760,
                height: 50,
                theme: "theme4",
                toolTip: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                axisX: {
                    gridThickness: 0.0,
                    interval: 60,
                    labelFontSize: 0.1,
                    tickLength: 0.0,
                    lineThickness: 1
                },

                axisY: {
                    gridThickness: 0.0,
                    interval: 10,
                    labelFontSize: 0.1,
                    tickLength: 0.0,
                    lineColor: "white",
                    lineThickness: 0.1
                },
                dataPointWidth: 2,
                dataPointMaxWidth: 5,
      data: [
      {
         type: "column",
         cursor: "pointer",
         click: onClick,
         dataPoints: Reviewed
    }]
 }
 );
    chart.render();
  }
  
function onClick(e) {
 alert('Element index is: ' + (e.dataPointIndex+1) + ', Position X:' + e.x + ',Position Y:'+ e.y);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, but still the above solution dint slove my problem. I want that position on loading of the graph not in the click event. as I menstioned in my first post, I could get the position of each column in click event.

Comment: I checked the website for chart control and it don't have load event

Comment: yes mbadeveloper. Thanks for your support. Is there any other mouse event / chart event which could help me to get the solution.? please let me know